# remove a PART of an Anchor Text with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove or change a **Part** of an anchor text.

My Anchor look like this:

```
<a href="http://something.com">Model 1234 motorbike</a>
```

I would like to remove the "motorbike" part of the anchor text, to end up with:

```
<a href="http://something.com">Model 1234</a>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

**update:**

The anchor links are coming from a different website. So I can't control the html. I'm simply trying to remove the "motorbike" part from the anchors sent, so it doesn't show up 100 times on my webpage.

@Shiv Kumar: yes, "motorbike" is always the last part of the anchor text. @Phrogz: the script is sending the available models to my site. The last part of the anchor text is always "motorbike", the first part changes: model 1234, type 4321 etc.

But I will give the codes a try first.

Thanks everyone for the quick replies.

Much appreciated.

Erik

Comment: its allway end with motorbike ?

Comment: How are you determining that "motorbike" is to be removed. Is it that you're always removing the last word? or is it that the word motorbike always exists?.

Comment: ...or is it that there is always "Model xxx" (where xxx are some digits) and you want to keep that?

Comment: @amphetamahine if your comment is in regards to my edit. Yes, it is, however paradigms are different and it's important not to mix the two (at least when possible).

Answer (score 2):

a) Modify the HTML sent to the browser, don't try to patch it up on the client. What if the user has JavaScript turned off?

b)

```
// Get rid of the last word in the text for all anchors referencing
// the domain something.com
$('a[href*="something.com"]').html(function(oldHTML){
  return oldHTML.replace(/\s\S+$/,'');
});

// Keep only "Model xxxx"
$('a[href*="something.com"]').html(function(oldHTML){
  return oldHTML.replace( /^(Model \d+).+/, '$1' );
});
```

**Edit**: To remove specifically the word 'motorbike' from every link:

```
$('a').html(function(oldHTML){
  return oldHTML.replace( ' motorbike', '' );
});
```

Comment: agreed that if possible, this should be solved on the server side... however, mostly search engine bots are likely to have JavaScript turned off these days, with all the facebook people everywhere... and for the rest - it does not compromise functionality, so it's still acceptable... btw: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add a className to filter links:

```
   $(".with_motorbike_txt").each(function() {
        var cur_txt = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(substring(0, cur_txt.indexOf('motorbike'));
    });
```